# Dygraph, parsing PHP/MYSQL output into chart

Tags: javascript, php, dygraphs

I'm attempting to use PHP to drag data from my MYSQL db (home IoT project) into a dygraph chart directly (rather than extracting, parsing into CSV file and then displaying, which seems unwieldy). I believe my route should work, but clearly I'm incorrect as it is not displaying correctly (small snippet here):

```
<html>
<head>
<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55)" alink="#ee0000" link="#0000ee" vlink="#551a8b">
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Test<br></span>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="dygraph.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="margin:0px auto" border="0" width="500" align="center">
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
<div id="graphdiv2"
style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
g2 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
<?php
$mysql_host = "localhost:3306";
$mysql_db = "mqtt";
$mysql_user = "*****";
$mysql_pw = "*****";
$connection = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pw, $mysql_db);
$mysql_table = "analog_data";
if (!$connection) {
    echo "Connection Error." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Message: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
/* Select queries return a resultset */
$result = $connection->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') AS date, datum, analog0, analog1 FROM ".$mysql_table); 
echo "[";  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$utime = strtotime($row[datum]); 
$diffutime = $utime - $lastutime; 
if ($diffutime > 600) { 
    echo "["."new Date(\"".$row['date']."\")".",NaN,NaN],"; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo "["."new Date(\"".$row['date']."\")".",".$row['analog0'].",".$row['analog1']."],"; 
        } 
    $lastutime = strtotime($row['datum']);
}
echo "]";
$_SESSION["dcount"] = $dcount;
mysqli_close($connection);
?>,
{rightGap: 20,
connectSeparatedPoints: true,
labels: [ "Datum", "A0", "A1" ] }          // options
);
</script>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<?php
    echo "<br>".$_SESSION["dcount"]." D ";
?>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

at the initial <?php

If I just use the php script alone in the page, it executes and displays the contents that I want to inject into the dygraph call, so I presume this is due to the attempt to execute the PHP *within* the call. However this appears to be how it is done in a number of online tutorials, this was the primary source https://geekynnotsogeeky.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/paasing-array-data-to-dygraphs-using-php/.

The source as parsed by chrome shows the full page code, it hasn't actually acted on any of the script.

Can anyone point me to an example of how this should be done, or explain what my stupid mistake has been?

Comment: Please share more details. That code snippet looks pretty strange from the beginning. How does the generated markup look like?

Comment: Did you save this file as *.php file? Because the error sounds like it's an .html file and the browser trips over the `<?php` while parsing JS code.

Comment: Hmm certainly I'll add more code, which I have slightly modified from the tutorial. I have tried running this both as a .php file as a trial, and as a .html file (which is the original form).

Comment: There's no need to add more code. Just answer the questions: how does the generated markup look like? Is PHP even evaluated?

Comment: Hi Nico, I assumed you needed more context by your request. I edited the post to point out the php doesn't seem to get evaluated at all in my browser - page source is basically the same as the original code.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve this? As nobody knows how you configured your webserver, it's close to impossible to provide help

Comment: As yet, nothing as I'm not thinking this is a server issue specifically. I have a range of php/database driven sites hosted on the same server, all working fine, and a simplified version of this code (just the php) evaluates fine to deliver the database contents from a file in the same folder. Hence I assumed it was the complication of inserting the php mid java script section of the HTML, or just that I've missed something simple.

Comment: PHP is able to run at any place, as far as your webserver is configured properly

Comment: Ahhhh now I see what you're getting at, and Chris G - it looks like I tried the whole page as .html and the original PHP-only page as .php. my server treats the .html as html only and doesn't evaluate the php, because it's not in a .php extension. Thanks for the pointers!